# Angular 2 exact RouterLinkActive including fragments?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

When using `routerLink` and `routerLinkActive` to apply CSS to a navigation bar, I'd like to also include the `fragment` information so that links are unique for sections within a homepage.

I've tried using `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` wihtout any luck.

The relevant part of the navigation bar code is:

```
  <li routerLinkActive="active"
      [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
    <a routerLink="/sitio" fragment="inicio">Inicio</a>
  </li>
  <li routerLinkActive="active"
      [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
    <a routerLink="/sitio" fragment="invierte">Invierte</a>
  </li>
  <li routerLinkActive="active"
      [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }">
    <a routerLink="/sitio" fragment="contacto">Contacto</a>
  </li>
```

The three different URLs the above code visits are:

- `/sitio#inicio`
- `/sitio#invierte`
- `/sitio#contacto`

But when clickin any of them, all of them are marked as being active (because they correspond to the `routerLink="/sitio"` and the `fragment=*` information is not included in the check. This results in the navigation bar looking like this when clicking on any of them:

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` this one working fine now with `"@angular/router": "^4.0.0"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an open issue to support that https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13205

`routerLinkActive` is a simple directive. You might be able to create a clone yourself with that extended functionality.

Comment: Here a fix you can implement : https://github.com/DzmitryShylovich/angular/commit/917c625698df03b4238febd9a153b11bc8076786#diff-4536fba7473dbee9eba3580a999b0e8a

Comment: This issue isn't implemented in Angular 4.0 yet and is still open.

Answer (score 12):

I just thought I would put how I solved it in case someone runs into the same problem: keep track of the current section in the site and use a class binding through a function in the component instead of using `routerLinkActive`.

The links in the template become:

```
<li [class.active]="isSectionActive('inicio')">
    <a routerLink="/sitio" fragment="inicio">Inicio</a>
</li>
<li [class.active]="isSectionActive('invierte')">
    <a routerLink="/sitio" fragment="invierte">Invierte</a>
</li>
<li [class.active]="isSectionActive('contacto')">
    <a routerLink="/sitio" fragment="contacto">Contacto</a>
</li>
```

Note the lack of use of `routerLinkActive`, and the use of class binding `[class.active]=isSectionActive('<name-of-section>')` instead.

The code that keeps track of the section we're inside of and decides whether or not to apply the CSS class in the template is:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

// Class signature... {

    private activeSiteSection: string;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private sessionService: SessionService
    ) {
        router.events.subscribe((event) => {
            if(event instanceof NavigationEnd ) {
                this.SiteURLActiveCheck(event);
            }
        });
    }

    private SiteURLActiveCheck(event: NavigationEnd): void {
        if (event.url.indexOf('#inicio') !== -1) {
            this.activeSiteSection = 'inicio';
        } else if (event.url.indexOf('#invierte') !== -1) {
            this.activeSiteSection = 'invierte';
        } else if (event.url.indexOf('#contacto') !== -1) {
            this.activeSiteSection = 'contacto';
        } else {
            this.activeSiteSection = '';
        }
    }

    private isSectionActive(section: string): boolean {
        return section === this.activeSiteSection;
    }
}
```

Probably overkill but I rather go this route than modify Angular 2's source. :)

Comment: Good solution but - as you said - a little bit overkill. Do you still use it like this?

Comment: @JavanR., I haven't worked with this stack for some time now. I'm not sure if it's still the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

Angular's `routerLinkActiveOptions` provides fragment, queryParam, matrixParam, and path matching in order to match the active route without custom solutions.

If you look at [RouteLinkActive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts#L100) you'll find it's a union:

```
routerLinkActiveOptions: { exact: boolean } | IsActiveMatchOptions;
```

Where [IsActiveMatchOptions](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/url_tree.ts#L23) expands on the configuration to determine whether a router link is active by matching on any combination on fragments, queryParams, matrixParams, and paths:

```
export interface IsActiveMatchOptions {
  matrixParams: 'exact'|'subset'|'ignored';
  queryParams: 'exact'|'subset'|'ignored';
  paths: 'exact'|'subset';
  fragment: 'exact'|'ignored';
}
```

You pass them into `routeLinkActiveOptions` instead of `{ exact: true }`:

```
<a [routerLinkActive]="linkActive"
   [routerLink]="linkCommands"
   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="linkActiveOptions"
   [fragment]="fragment">...</a>
```

Created a quick [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1vekqs?file=src/app/app.component.html) to demonstrate usage using a fragment:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1vekqs?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: This is the cleanest solution and in my opinion, the best practice to solve this problem. It should be accepted as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I struggle to work with `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` even on the Angular 7.

So, I used the following trick to solve this issue. The answer is `ActivatedRoute`.

in the `Component`.

```
class ComponentClass{
  activeFragment = this.route.fragment.pipe(share()); 
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute){}
}
```

In the `template` use this as follows.

```
<li [class.active]="(activeFragment | async)==='inicio'">
    <a routerLink="/sitio" fragment="inicio">Inicio</a>
</li>
<li [class.active]="(activeFragment | async)==='invierte'">
    <a routerLink="/sitio" fragment="invierte">Invierte</a>
</li>
<li [class.active]="(activeFragment | async)==='contacto'">
    <a routerLink="/sitio" fragment="contacto">Contacto</a>
</li
```

I am not sure about the `share` operator here. I haven't looked into it if its multicast by default. 
Let me know if you have an answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

Making Omar Trejo's approach simpler. Rather than subscribing to the Route, I updated the isSectionActive to look at location.href to make it work.

```
private isSectionActive(section: string): boolean {
    return location.href.indexOf(section) !== -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that Omar suggested worked, however, when I have a fragment that contains the name of another fragment in the name, a conflict is generated.

For example, a fragment called tab and another called table, when activating the table fragment, the tab will also be activated, as it has the word tab in its name.

I made some changes to this solution and I hope it helps other people.

component.ts

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

isSectionActive(section: string): boolean {
  let element = false;
  this.route.fragment.subscribe((fragment: string) => {
    element = fragment === section.split("#").pop();
  });
  return element;
}
```

component.html

```
<button type="button" class="item" [routerLink]="['/components/tutorial']" [fragment]="fragmentName" [class.active]="isSectionActive(fragmentName)">{{fragmentName}}</button>
```

Comment: it would be a heavyweight approach while using it in such components which are commonly used everywhere in the application. e.g : Headercomponent